# Dynamic Breadcrumbs URL

Tags: php, html, css, breadcrumbs

I have found this code online and it pretty much does what I would like it todo but there are just a few issues.

When I click on the home tab it adds https in front of the domain and it says this website is not available but if I remove the s it works.

also on the websites there are titles like home > aaa-bbb-ccc > aaa-bbb > aaa I will supply the old breadcrumb code we have and i'm wondering if we specify the url for the breadcrumbs.

Also when I view the website in the browser in the middle of the breadcrumb this appears Home > $title > index

Old Breadcrumbs:

```
    <?php
/*
Copyright Justin Whitford 2006.
  http://www.whitford.id.au/
Perpetual, non-exclusive license to use this code is granted
on the condition that this notice is left in tact.
*/
function breadcrumbs(){
  $bread = explode('/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
  $url = '/';
  $returnString = "<span class='bc0'><a href='$url'>Home</a>";
  for($i=1;$i<count($bread)-1;$i++){
    $url.=$bread[$i].'/';
    $returnString .= " ></span> <span class='bc$i'><a href='$url'>"
      .prettify($bread[$i])."</a>";
  }
  echo $returnString.'</span>';
}
function prettify($dirName){

$directoryName['aaa-bbb-ccc']='Locate Us';
$directoryName['aaa-bbb']='Contact';

  $directoryName['breadcrumbs']='Foe';
  if($directoryName[$dirName]!=''){
    $dirName=$directoryName[$dirName];
  }else{
    $dirName = str_replace('_', ' ', $dirName);
    $dirName = str_replace('%20', ' ', $dirName);
    $dirName = ucwords(strtolower($dirName));
  }
  return $dirName;
}
```

This is my new code:

```
<?php
function breadcrumbs($separator = ' > ', $home = 'Home') {

$path = array_filter(explode('/', parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)));
$base_url = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
$breadcrumbs = array("<a href=\"$base_url\">$home</a>");

$last = end(array_keys($path));

foreach ($path AS $x => $crumb) {
$title = ucwords(str_replace(array('.php', '_'), Array('', ' '), $crumb));
if ($x != $last){
$breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="$base_url$crumb">$title</a>';
}else{
$breadcrumbs[] = $title;
}
}

return implode($separator, $breadcrumbs);
}


echo breadcrumbs();
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: is your domain is an `https` one?

Comment: @Arun No it is not its just a `http://www.`

Comment: I mean whether the url starts with 'https://' or 'http://'. I fit is not 'https://' then '$base_url = ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] ? "https" : "http") . "://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . "/";' may cause error

Comment: domain is just `http://`

Comment: try to use `$base_url = "http://". $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/"`. and remove that checking

Comment: @Arun Nice yeah that worked perfectly, any chance helping with the other 2? if not thanks.

Comment: you are printing $title as a string, you want to concat the variable, like so: $breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="$base_url$crumb">'.$title.'</a>';

Comment: with pleasure..please feel free to ask

Comment: @Jens-AndréKoch Nice Jens thank you working much better now but it i click to go back to the previous page on the breadcrumb its adds this to the end of the URL /$base_url$crumb i would like it to link the the relevant page

Comment: @Arun cheers :) because its picking up the URL they are like this aaa-bbb-ccc > aaa-bbb-ccc how can i remove the - and either display the name without the - or choose what I would like to call it instead. I know that i will need to use explode but where would i place it. Thanks for you help so far.

Comment: please accept the below answer. :) you have to use explode for this. Just use it on the php page where you get the values `aaa-bbb-ccc > aaa-bbb-ccc`

Comment: @Arun I want to use this dynamically so it will do it in one file and work across the whole website. I will accept when Ive got it fully working :)

Comment: are you using an `MVC` structure?then you can do it once for the whole website. otherwise it may not achieve. If it is `MVC` then please try it at the page where you get the `bredcrumb` data

Comment: @Arun no its not on an MVC I will just include the file and use `echo breadcrumbs();` on each page.

Comment: then define the paths just before including your file. And then give the path variable in your code.what is the content in `breadcrumbs()`???

Comment: @Arun ill add the php file in externally and use echo breadcrumbs(); to make the code work. Where would I add the Explode and also when I click to go back to the previous page on the breadcrumb its adds this to the end of the URL /$base_url$crumb and makes the page not display I would like it to link the the relevant page

Comment: @Arun this line is one of my problems                             $breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="$base_url$crumb">'.$title.'</a>';

Comment: @Arun ive amended my code little more now it goes back but how can i remove the - between the words. ive edited my original post

Comment: from where you get `$title`? is that contain `aaa-bbb-ccc > aaa-bbb-ccc`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use

```
$base_url = "http://". $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/"`
```

and remove that checking. It is because at first check `$_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https' : 'http')` may return `https`. Use that only if you have a secured domain. That is an 'https://' domain

Comment: i'm still having a few problems with explode function i cant see where to put the explode function.